# Finding $\int \frac{\sqrt{\cot(x)} - \sqrt{\tan(x)}}{4+3 \sin^2 (x)} \ \mathrm d x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How can we find the indefinite integral for:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\cot(x)} - \sqrt{\tan(x)}}{4+3 \sin^2 (x)} \ \mathrm d x$$

I tried expressing the denominator in $\sin x+\cos x$ form since we have its derivative in numerator but I am not able to proceed. Please help me out.

Comment: How to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/29979#29979). Where is this problem from?

Comment: It is from my Calculus Course book . I am in 12th Grade so I just know some basic integration

Comment: @ZAhmed I believe the combination of the hypergeometric functions in Mathematica simplify to an elementary expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By some basic trigonometric identities, one has
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\cot(x)} - \sqrt{\tan(x)}}{4+3 \sin^2 (x)}~dx=\int \frac{\sec^2(x)(1-\tan(x))}{\sqrt{\tan(x)}(7\tan^2(x)+4)}~dx,$$
which motivates the substitution $u=\tan(x)$. This leads to
$$\int \frac{1-u}{\sqrt{u}(7u^2+4)}~du,$$
whose integrand can be converted to a rational expression via the substitution $u=v^2$. The resulting expression can be solved using partial fractions.

Comment: Thank you for your solution :) @ projectilemotion